# navigate through JS object

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-sqs

I am trying to navigate through a Javascript object but everytime I get an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Attributes' of undefined

Here's my code:

```
var attributes = [];
var params = {
  QueueUrl: 'AMAZON_QUEUE', /* required */
  AttributeNames: [
    'ApproximateNumberOfMessages',
    /* more items */
  ]
};
setInterval(queueAttributes, 2000) 

function queueAttributes () {
sqs.getQueueAttributes(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else  console.log (data);   
        attributes.push(data);           // successful response
        setTimeout(queueChecker, 1000);
});
}

function queueChecker (attributes) {
if (attributes.Attributes.ApproximateNumberOfMessages == 0) {
    console.log ('queueEmpty');
}
else
{
    console.log (attributes.Attributes.ApproximateNumberOfMessages + 'messages in queue');
};
}
```

Anyone has any idea on how I should call the ApproximateNumberOfMessages value contained within my attributes variable?

The response that I am getting from SQS and therefore the content of the attributes variable is as follow:

```
  { ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: '6c43d9d6-281d-5bfa-b7f5-94e165b49662' },
  Attributes: { ApproximateNumberOfMessages: '0' } }
```

Thanks.

Comment: because you do not pass an object to queueChecker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing attributes as an array.

```
attributes.push(data);
```

Keeps on adding elements in the array attributes. If you wish to access attributes in the manner

```
attributes.Attributes.ApproximateNumberOfMessages
```

You need to declare attributes as an object:

```
var attributes = {
   Attributes:{
      ApproximateNumberOfMessages:0
   }
}
```

Then in your function queueAttributes(), you can populate the attributes object as follows...

```
function queueAttributes () {
   sqs.getQueueAttributes(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else  console.log (data);   

        //attributes.push(data);           // successful response
        attributes.Attributes.ApproximateNumberOfMessages = data;
        setTimeout(queueChecker, 1000);
  });
}
```

Assuming data is to be populated in attributes.Attributes.ApproximateNumberOfMessages.

Hope it helps!